# What is the difference between a software BOT, "an executable that always runs" and a software server?

Tags: bots, botframework, azure-cognitive-services

What is the difference between a software BOT, "an executable that always runs" and a software server?

Trying to understand if i write a windows service that always runs and responds to user data then what would be its difference from a software bot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more semantics than mechanics. In Bot Framework terms, a bot is a conversational user interface (CUI). It's purpose is to interact with a human (or possibly other bots) using natural language. The main purpose is to use natural language for communication, as opposed to graphical user interfaces (GUI) that require point and click or mobile user interfaces that you touch.

In many ways, the lines are blurred in how you communicate with the bot because the user interface might let you choose numbers from a menu or push buttons, but the conversational interface will always be present. The bot developer could build a user interface that's no more sophisticated than a console application, but that wouldn't be in the spirit of bots. The more you move away from conversation, the less botness your application has. Instead, a more natural interface using an Natural Language Processing (NLP) backend would be better. Microsoft has LUIS.ai and there are other vendors with NLP APIs that you could use too.

If you wrote a server application that chatted with the user, like a bot does, then it seems you could call your server application a bot. However, a server application could also do many things unrelated to the Bot Framework concept of what a bot is. Bots, spiders, and other such software have been around for years and I'm not saying those aren't bots. However, when you're discussing bots from platforms like Bot Framework, or other Messaging platforms, it's normal to assume they aspire to some form of CUI.

Comment: Thank you Joe, this is exactly what I was looking for.